# Why has my image padding-bottom despite no padding in fact?

Tags: html, css, padding

Here is [demo](http://jsbin.com/odotig/3/edit#preview)...

In css code, I didn't write any padding but image has padding-bottom. 
Here is html codes :

```
<div class="image_block">
   <img width="100" height="100" alt="Facebook" src="http://i.imwx.com/web/tv/
     programs/facebook_logo_100x100.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is css code :

```
body {
    background-color:#131211;
}

.image_block {
    border:1px solid #b5b5b5;
    float:left;

}
```

Comment: You should use a reset css (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Some browsers apply basic styling by default.

Comment: Your image looks like it has about 3px of whitespace all around the actual logo. Are you sure you aren't mistaking that for padding?

Comment: I know. I tried different logos. But when you look carefully, bottom has more spaces than others. I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image_block div has 104px in height, there's no padding there

Just set it to `height:100px;`

Comment: yes you right. It works. But how could you understand 104px. There is no 104px anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was with 104px, it would take more time to track down the source of the error. Instead, I inspected it with Opera's Dragonfly and saw the 104px (Firebug or any other dev tool would help to find this - you really should use one)